# Issue with Jquery click not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building an eCommerce Application where the user can select the option and the shopping cart is automatically updated through jquery.

The user will have few radio button to choose from and as he selects the radio button, the shopping cart is updated.

Now, the issue I am facing is, when he taps on the radio button ( Mobile website), some times, the callback function is not called at all so the shopping card is not updated.

I am not an expert, but can you please tell me if I am missing anything. Here is the code I am using.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="col-33">
    <div class="panel1 panel-primary text-center no-border">
        <div class="panel-body blue">

            <label>
                <input type="radio"  name="recharge_amount"  value="{var name='price_id'}"/><br/>{var name='grand_total1'}
                <input type="hidden"  id="carttotal_{var name='price_id'}"      value="{var name='carttotal'}"/>        
                <input type="hidden"  id="taxper_{var name='price_id'}"         value="{var name='taxper'}"/>       
                <input type="hidden"  id="taxamount_{var name='price_id'}"      value="{var name='taxamount'}"/>        
                <input type="hidden"  id="grand_total_{var name='price_id'}"    value="{var name='grand_total'}"/>      


            </label>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#transfer_target input[type="radio"]').click(function()
        {

            $('#cart_total').hide();
            var $amt = $(this).val();

            var carttotal_el    = "#carttotal_" + $amt;
            var taxper_el       = "#taxper_" + $amt;
            var taxamount_el    = "#taxamount_" + $amt;
            var grand_total_el  = "#grand_total_" + $amt;

            //update_price_list($amt);

            var $carttotal = $('#carttotal');   
            $carttotal.html($(carttotal_el).val());

            var $salestax_per = $('#salestax_per');
            var $str = '<h4>Sales Tax(' + $(taxper_el).val() + ')</h4>';
            $salestax_per.html($str);

            var $salestax_amount = $('#salestax_amount');   
            $salestax_amount.html($(taxamount_el).val());

            var $grand_total = $('#grand_total');   
            $grand_total.html($(grand_total_el).val());

            $('#cart_total').show();

        });
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the HTML code this script is referring to?

Comment: Make sure that if you have any other cilck handlers on this element, or child elements, they don't do `e.preventDefault()` nor `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Show the HTML and check to make sure there are no console errors.

Comment: Try to `console.log` `$('#transfer_target input[type="radio"]')` before the binding of callback and check if it is not empty.

Comment: There is not any other click handles I tried $('#transfer_target input[type="radio"]') on the console. Also, when I simulate on Google chrome on Desktop, it works. However, the problem seems to occur only on a mobile browser.

Comment: Did you even use the id - "#transfer_target" this on any parent of the radio button? I dont see it in ur HTML

Comment: The HTML is only a part. Yes, I did use the "#transfer_target" for the Form

Comment: No, I am sorry, it is not live currently,

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a DOM Ready function? You should have something that looks like this. It may simply be that the data is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  someName();
});

function someName() {
  $('#transfer_target input[type="radio"]').click(function() {


          $('#cart_total').hide();
          var $amt = $(this).val();

          var carttotal_el    = "#carttotal_" + $amt;
          var taxper_el       = "#taxper_" + $amt;
          var taxamount_el    = "#taxamount_" + $amt;
          var grand_total_el  = "#grand_total_" + $amt;

          var $carttotal = $('#carttotal');   
          $carttotal.html($(carttotal_el).val());

          var $salestax_per = $('#salestax_per');
          var $str = '<h4>Sales Tax(' + $(taxper_el).val() + ')</h4>';
          $salestax_per.html($str);

          var $salestax_amount = $('#salestax_amount');   
          $salestax_amount.html($(taxamount_el).val());

          var $grand_total = $('#grand_total');   
          $grand_total.html($(grand_total_el).val());

          $('#cart_total').show();
      });
```

}